# shell: build a comma separated list ended with a period

Tags: string, shell, sh

In a shell exercice I'm asked to build from a newline separated list a ", " separated list with a final period like that:

```
abc
def
hij
```

would becomes:

```
abc, def, hij.
```

They ask me to "write a command line". I tried using `tr` and `paste` but I can't get the whitespace and the final period is problematic.

I'm a bit lost, I can't think of any command that could help me for that. Could someone give me some clue?

NB: what exactly I'm asked for is the following:

> Write a command line that displays the output of a cat /etc/passwd command,
> removing comments, every other line starting from the second line, reversing each lo-
> gin, sorted in reverse alphabetical order, and keeping only logins between FT_LINE1
> and FT_LINE2 included, and they must separated by ", " (without quotation
> marks), and the output must end with a ".".

I currently have that line (doesn't do the comma/period thing):

```
cat /etc/passwd | sed '/^#/d' | awk -F ':' 'NR % 2 == 0 {print $1}' | rev | sort -r | sed -n "$FT_LINE1,$FT_LINE2p"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo -e "abc\ndef\nhij" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g'
```

explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/2235381

Comment: I haven't read the linked answer yet, put copy pasting your example doesn't work. I'm on macos, does that change the newline character, maybe?

Comment: separating commands like this works:
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/, /g'